# Web Service Questions/Advice, Android

Tags: android, web-services

I need some advice and I am fairly new to Android Development.

There is a website that acts as a dashboard UI to access all the data being housed in a SQL database. The company had previously hired a developer to build iOS software that communicated with this remote database via iPad, iPhone etc. Well now they are looking to build an Android compatible application. I am hoping that the previously built web service file(s) are able to be re-used for the Android application. They will be using REST/JSON to send/receive info. However they are no longer in contact with the iOS developer. So although we have backend access to all the files we have no idea where the web service file(s) are located or how they were labeled. So my questions:

- Will the web service files be reusable for REST/JSON data transfer? The company believes they were written in PHP.
- There are a lot of files and it might take quite a while to find the
  web service file(s). Even if they are reusable would it be smarter
  to just start from scratch?
- When I finally figure out the first two questions the most basic one remains, am I making http requests to the website URL i.e. "*something.com/webservicefile.php*" or the control panel URL i.e. "*10.29.293.393/webservicefile.php*"?

Because I'm a novice I understand I might not be asking the right questions, so if more info is needed please just drop a comment and I'll do my best. Thanks for the help/advice. Links are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If it's a REST/JSON interface you should be able to easily use it from an android client.
2. If you only need to create an android client and the iOS client and server are working fine I would definitely not start from scratch unless your employer has money to burn.
3. You could setup a proxy for an iOS client and see what it is hitting.  You could also look at the access log for the server to see what URLs are being requested.  Finally, you could get into the PHP code and figure out what it's doing and what the endpoints of your service are.

Comment: excellent answers, thank you so much. I guess this is all about me finding these web service files then. Any advice on finding these files, aka typical folder/file names? I know it's a vague question. I'm just hoping that there's some kind of standard in naming these files/folders. (Probably not though)